# What's the equilvalent of Ninject When clause in Autofac?

Tags: autofac

Let's say we have a class with two constructor, first is empty(the default), and the second with constructor parameter.

```
class Test : ITest {
     Public Test () {}
     public Test (string parameter) { do something; }
```

In NInject, it can use:

```
Bind<ITest>().To<Test>();

Bind<ITest>().To<Test>()
            .When(ctx => IsTrue())
            .WithConstructorArgument("parameter", request => GetParameter());
```

It's very concised for conditional constructor usage.

I'm wondering what's the equilvalent in Autofac?

Pleae help!

Answer (score 1):

You can register a delegate that does the conditional logic. E.g. :

```
builder.Register(context => IsTrue() ? firstService : theOtherService);
```

Comment: This doesn't deal with how to assign parameter to constrcutor. I had change question with more details. Thanks for helping.